# Convert binary data to valid image format, using Imagemagick (or other tool)

Tags: conversion, imagemagick

I have raw binary data in a file. I know that it is "8-BPP monochrome" and I know width and height of image. How could I convert this data to any readable image format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around for few hours finally got this sorted:

> convert -size 280x352 -depth 8 gray:out_gray out_normal.png

Comment: out_gray is file name of raw binary data